# npm install is not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs, bower, yeoman

I used this installation guide to install nodejs:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

I am trying to use npm install and I had this error when I used this command:

```
npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/alexfqc/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/alexfqc/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/alexfqc/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/home/alexfqc/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I was following the yeoman [instructions](http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html), and there is a [page](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) for this error

After do this steps the error still continue.

Then I tried this commands:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/alexfqc/.npm-packages
sudo chown -R root /home/alexfqc/.npm-packages
```

and did not work.

I am trying the entire day install nodejs correctly to use yeoman, bower and grunt but it seems impossible.

I tried other [ways](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) of installing nodejs but another error appeared.

I anyone could help to fix this error or show a way to install the nodejs, yeoman, bower and grunt I would be very grateful.

Comment: After a lot of work, I found the solution. Go to https://nodejs.org/ and download by the oficial site then everything will work correctely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an access error, try using `sudo npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli` to perform install as root

Alternate - Instead of giving ownership of folder to root, give it to your user account with: `sudo chown -R $USER /home/alexfqc/.npm-packages`

Comment: I am trying to do this from the correct way, not with workaround.
In this link: http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html they say to not do that

Comment: with sudo chown -R root you are giving ownership to root, you are supposed to give ownership to your user account with sudo chown -r $USER